# x2goclient disconnects immediately

Tags: x2go, x2goclient

I'm trying to connect to Debian server with x2go installed, its able to connect by password to ssh (because if password is wrong, it says explicitely). But when connection is almost established, there is a black x2go screen, then log shows this:

[image]

and disconnects immediately. How can I diagnose and fix this?

I tried installing GNOME, XFCE and MATE desktop on this Debian machine, and changing corresponding connection mode on client: nothing helps.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: FYI:  I can't see what difference changing the DE part of the stack would be expected to have; you mention three different GTK3 environments (*maybe GTK2 or part GTK2/GTK3 for Xfce if you're on an older release as you didn't specify*)